# GARCH Option Pricing in R

Tags: option-pricing, programming, monte-carlo, garch

I am trying to code a GARCH option pricing model in R. I am still new to R so this does seem a bit complicated.

I want to estimate an asymmetric GARCH model as well as an EGARCH model. This I have done somewhat successfully. However, now I have to find the option prices using Monte Carlo simulation.

The option to be priced is a plain vanilla Call option.

Does anyone know how to price such an option?

This would be greatly appreciated!

Best regards

August

Comment: Do some of these resources help? [Christoffersen and Jacobs (2004)](https://www.jstor.org/stable/30046228?seq=1), [Duan (1995)](https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/abs/10.1111/j.1467-9965.1995.tb00099.x), [Heston and Nandi (2000)](https://academic.oup.com/rfs/article/13/3/585/1576522?login=true). Perhaps even this [book](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-3-662-45037-6)?

Comment: Hey @August, are you making any progress with your option pricing work?